# Insert Records into Database using JobListener of JSR-352

Tags: transactions, listener, spring-batch, jsr352

I am trying to insert some records in the afterJob() method of the JobListener implementation. My Listener looks as follows,

```
public class SampleListener2 implements JobListener {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    public void beforeJob() throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void afterJob() throws Exception {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        List<Object[]> objectList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        Object[] objectArray = {System.currentTimeMillis(), "After Job", "After Job", "1.0"};
        objectList.add(objectArray);

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into RAW_REPORT(DATE,IMPRESSIONS,CLICKS,EARNINGS) values (?,?, ?, ?)", objectList);

        System.out.println("After Job 2");


}
```

On Debugging I found that Spring-Batch is not committing the transactions resulting the records not getting displayed in the DB. If i manually try to commit the transaction I am able to find by records in DB

```
public class SampleListener2 implements JobListener {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob() throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void afterJob() throws Exception {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());

        List<Object[]> objectList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        Object[] objectArray = {System.currentTimeMillis(), "Before Job", "Before Job", "1.0"};
        objectList.add(objectArray);

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into RAW_REPORT(DATE,IMPRESSIONS,CLICKS,EARNINGS) values (?,?, ?, ?)", objectList);
        transactionManager.commit(status);
        System.out.println("Before Job 1");
    }

}
```

Can someone let me know the details of this behaviour, I would prefer not to handle the transactions manually and want spring-batch to commit my records in the Listener. request for your help on this issue

**Edit:**
Sample Code to test the scenario:
https://github.com/rbutti/SpringBatch/tree/master/SpringJSR352

Comment: Where are you running this?  How is your datasource and transaction manager configured?

Comment: I am running this as an standalone application. Datasource and transaction manager have been configured successfully and various rollback and commit scenarios have been tested. Currently I am using mysql database and you can find the SQL script and the code I have used for testing mentioned in my above edit